# Battery went from 85% to 32%

Tags: battery

I have two cell phones, one is for work the other is personal. I had them stacked on top of one another on my desk. All of a sudden my work phone went completely dead from about 75% full, and my Android went from 85% to 32%. What gives?

Comment: If they are more than 12-18 months old, the batteries could be bad... otherwise try recalibrating the batteries, run them until they power off on their own, fully charge them with the power off, then turn on and repeat the cycle once.

Comment: This is just a hunch. I think they were interfering each other radio signal. I can't site any evidence. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's winter, your phone was probably very cold. I've had problems like that too. My phone went from 6% to dead. Then I heated it back up to room temperature, turned it back on and it was at 26%. If it was a normal condition, and it happens again, consider replacing your battery.